# Display flex and wrapping a text in span tag gives unwanted spacing between words

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have set display flex for parent element because I need pseudo element and the text be next to each other. But I also put part of the text inside span tag to make it more light, but in that case, display flex also distribute spacing between my words outside span tag. Here you see:

[image]

Instead I need `in products and services` be displayed like a normal sentence because it's part of the same p tag div, it's just that the first few words are wrapped in span tag too.

The code:

```css
#page-sub-header p {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  display: flex;
}

#page-sub-header p:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(rectangle.jpg);
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="sub_container">
        <p class="header_tag">
          <span>Maintaining only the highest standards of quality</span> in products and services.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of the php add the real html and text that you refer to.

Comment: @Dejan.S Updated. Anything else while I'm learning to ask question on SO? Working code snippet maybe? Coz if that's why I my question gets downvoted, I want to fix it.

Comment: It got down voted because of it contained the php yes, so it wasn't working code snippet. You can read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i don't see the need of flex here ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I don't use flex, I get the same layout but on mobile the last words are wrapping and dropping under the red rectangle on the left. If I use flex it gets displayed without wrapping in one nice block next to red rectangle.

Comment: share your full code with CSS ;) and you will see that we can do this without flex

Comment: This is full code there is nothing more to it. I could drop the flex and make pseudo element be 100% height of the `p` element it is attached to, to prevent text wrapping around pseudo on small screens, but for some reason then I delete fixed `150px` height for it and change it to 100% the red rectangle disappears.

Comment: I'm sorry there was missing `float:left` for pseudo element. Added it to the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things is going on here:

- the rightmost, unwrapped, text becomes an anonymous flex item, which is kind of equal to have it wrapped (which I did in below sample to show how it all behaves).
- the space you get is because when the inner left `span` wraps its text, the `span` itself aren't aware of that and won't adjust its width.
  This is the box models default behavior, and happens whether you use Flexbox or not.

So either you need a script to calculate and adjust the left `span`'s width, or use a media query.

*As a note, the `display: block`, and the edited `float: left`, has no impact since the pseudo is a flex item, also, the `float: left` can actually cause issues as well on some browsers.*

Stack snippet - with added borders so you can see how it behaves when resize the browsers width.

```css
p {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  display: flex;
}
p span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p:before {
  content: "";
  /*display: block;         does not apply on flex item's  */
  width: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="sub_container">
        <p class="header_tag">
          <span>Maintaining only the highest standards of quality</span> <span>in products and services.</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But what do you mean use media query? How can that solve my problem?

Comment: And also a quick question, is there a way to stop text wrapping around floated pseudo element? I know I can prevent wrapping with `overflow:hidden` on usual divs, but on pseudo it don't seem to be working.

Comment: @Limpuls Since you use full browser window width, and with a given font size, you can at certain break points adjust the width of the left `span`, e.g. like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h5jr5LLn/

Comment: @Limpuls If you with _stop wrapping around_ mean the text should have its left edge aligned, with a left align pseudo that has a given width, you can instead position it absolute and give either the parent a matching padding or the children a left margin. If you can't get it to work with my suggestion, provide a fiddle sample to me and I'll have a look whether it is a quick fix or should be posted as a new question.

Comment: I tried making the pseudo to be absolute positioned and it works, no more wrapping of text around, but I can't seem to find a way to put some spacing with margins or paddings... Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Limpuls/rhcfw07p/3/

Comment: @Limpuls Use padding and left (see notes in CSS): https://jsfiddle.net/rhcfw07p/8/